# How to access XML files through the URL

Tags: java, xml, configuration, struts2

I am a beginner in Struts 2 and I am stuck in an issue, I would like to access an `.xml` file in the project `doc`, when the user goes to the link `www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml`. But right now I can only access it by going to the URL `www.sitename.com/sitemap`, i.e. without the extension. When I specify the action name as `sitemap.xml` it does not work. How could I make the user access the URL `www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml`. Sorry If the question does not make any sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17293115/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard extension in Struts 2 for action name is `.action`. But it's configurable via using a setting `struts.action.extension`. It's available in the `default.properties`, which is  used by the default action mapper.

You might use a comma separated list, e.g. `struts.action.extension=action,xml,whatsoever`
The blank extension used to map directories treated as action names. Static content is mapped via specifying a blank extension, e.g. `struts.action.extension=`, or `struts.action.extension=a,b,c,,`, or `struts.action.extension=a,,b,c`.

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply@Roman.But i would like to ask if a doubt,If i have an action named "home" and i have changed my `struts.action.extension` as you said,does that mean i can access my home page as home.xml.??

Comment: You can only provide extensions listed by your configuration settings, when you make a request an extension will be extracted from url and added to action mapping.

Comment: Is there some way by which i could provide an extension for a particular action call..??

Comment: You can only provide the extension in `struts.xml` or `struts.properties`.