# How see wsdl using Struts 2 in browser

Tags: web-services, jboss, struts2, wsdl, action-mapping

I have implemented a web service in my project. I also have deployed project on JBoss server successfully. I can see web service in jboss admin console in Web Service section. when i open wsdl url in browser it tells :

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [AddNumbers] associated with context path [/TEST].

The url that i am opening in browser is `http://localhost:8085/TEST/AddNumbers?wsdl`

How map wsdl in `struts.xml` file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17293115/1700321.

Comment: Does `excludePattern` not working for you? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the struts 2 filter is configured to map those requests. You should add `excludePattern` constant to `struts.xml` to exclude some URLs from Struts processing. More about this you can find in [Preventing Struts from Handling a Request](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/static-content.html#preventing-struts-from-handling-a-request).

> Since Struts 2.1.7, you are able to provide a comma separated list of patterns for which when matching against the
> request URL the Filter will just pass by. This is done via the configuration option `struts.action.excludePattern`, for example in your `struts.xml`

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*\?wsdl,/some/conent/?.*"/>
    ...
 
</struts>
```