# Struts2 excludePattern for rest implementation

Tags: java, rest, struts2

I have an application halfway completed where the rest web services calls are implemented by bypassing the Struts2 filter dispatcher.

the **web.xml** was implemented as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <display-name>Rabbit</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/jsps/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.webservice.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now as I had to implement *struts2-jquery* plugin I had to change *web.xml* to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <display-name>Rabbit</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/jsps/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.webservice.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

All is fine **except** tha the rest calls are not working so I wanted to implement a **excludePatterns** in my *struts configuration file*
with something like this

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest"></constant>
    <include file="authenticate-config.xml" />
    <include file="functional-config.xml" /> 
</struts>
```

But this is not working.
Can someone suggest me how do I get this working. I need to exclude the calls formed by urls with `http://...APP/rest/...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17293115/1700321.

Comment: You were almost there, +1

Comment: Note: `excludePattern` exists since `2.1.7`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Ya almost there, as the saying goes missed by a whisker lol