# Regarding filter mapping and servlet mapping in web.xml

Tags: java, rest, struts2

I am using Strust2 and restful services in my current project. In web.xml we are using filter mapping and servlet mapping as shown below web.xml link

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servletclass>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filterclass>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/struts2/*</url-pattern>   
    </filter-mapping>
```

According to configuration of web.xml, All restful services are executing successfully and strusts action class is calling but JSP pages are not executing.
Moreover I should not change the url pattern of servlet mapping as shown below

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Because these restful service using by somebody else.  Is there any way to execute jsp pages successfully? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using jersey 1.18 jars only. Still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Please visit linked question to see how this can be configured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can unable to change servlet url pattern because somebody using these urls. but jsp pages are not executing  because of this url pattern. So pls let me know is there any way if possible

Comment: Why not? Map other url-s and exclude them from S2.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17293115/1700321.